# How do I retrieve the new value of an intent after restarting an activity, and not the original one?

Tags: android, android-intent, onnewintent

There's a lot of questions about this already, and I feel like my code should work. 
What I'm trying to  do is Activity A starts Activity B, sending an intent.  Activity B then starts Activity A for result, and a new Intent should be received. My code is below, and according to the quote from the documentation below, the code should be working:

> The "standard" and "singleTop" modes differ from each other in just one >respect: Every time there's new intent for a "standard" activity, a new >instance of the class is created to respond to that intent. Each instance >handles a single intent. Similarly, a new instance of a "singleTop" activity >may also be created to handle a new intent. However, if the target task >already has an existing instance of the activity at the top of its stack, >that instance will receive the new intent (in an onNewIntent() call); a new >instance is not created.

So based on that, my code is as follows:
P.S My onNewIntent(Intent) doesn't get called, Im wondering if i put it in the right class.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink_sale_list);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    mDrinksAdapter = new drinksAdapter(getApplicationContext(), drinks, drinkPics);
    mListView.setAdapter(mDrinksAdapter);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    //If the bn!= null, this means that this activity was started by Activity B via startActivityForResult()

            Bundle bn = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(bn != null){

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putSerializable("anotherDrinkObject", drinks.get(position));
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

                    finish();

            }
            else {

                Intent intent = new Intent(drinkSaleList.this, SaleActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("DrinkObject", drinks.get(position));
                intent.putExtras(bundle);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

    });
}
```

}

Activity B

```
public class SaleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView mListView;
private drinksAdapter mDrinksAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_sale);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sale);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    Drink drink = (Drink) bundle.getSerializable("DrinkObject");

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.saleList);
    mDrinksAdapter = new drinksAdapter(getApplicationContext(), drink);
    mListView.setAdapter(mDrinksAdapter);

    Button addDrink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addAnotherDrink);

    addDrink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SaleActivity.this, drinkSaleList.class);
            intent.removeExtra("DrinkObject");
            intent.putExtra("anotherDrink", true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

        }
    });

}
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);//must store the new intent unless getIntent() will return the old one


}




public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            Bundle bn = getIntent().getExtras();

            Drink drink = (Drink) bn.getSerializable("anotherDrinkObject");

            mDrinksAdapter.add(drink);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I've never had this scenario before but I understand the part you quoted like "onNewIntent()" has to be in Activity A. Activity B will get the results in "onActivityResult()" as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You want to receive the result from `Activity B` in `Activity A` so when you are starting `Activity B`, use `startActivityForResult` and `override` `onActivityResult` in `Activity A` and you will now receive resultant intent in `onActivityResult

Hope this helps.`

Comment: please read question: " Activity B then starts Activity A for result"

Comment: Ok. You will receive the result in `onActivityResult`. override this function in `Activity B`

Comment: that's all right, just edit the answer ;)  But the real problem is that OP wants to use "Activity.onNewIntent()" and is wondering where to place the method?

Comment: set intent `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` while starting `Activity B`, you will recieve intent in `onNewIntent` of `Activity B`

Comment: I tried this Mustansar, however,  it still does not work

Comment: which code calls Activity B, setResult or startActivity from Activity A?